# Google Chrome extension that can allow copying text

Tags: chrome, text-processing, copy-paste

I am looking for a Google Chrome extension that can allow copying text when it has been disabled by the website.

I am aware of the Google Chrome extension [Allow Copy](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-copy/abidndjnodakeaicodfpgcnlkpppapah?hl=en-US) but it doesn't work in some cases, e.g. it doesn't work on http://www.razerzone.com/gaming-systems/razer-blade-pro

A similar question was posted by [Deepak Kumar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4951026/deepak-kumar) on [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30608663/395857).

Comment: `document.designMode = "on"` also comes in handy.

Comment: You can temporarily disable javascript.

Comment: i'm not sure what's your goal on http://www.razerzone.com/gaming-systems/razer-blade-pro, but with firefox i can mark&copy everything (also the images) without any complaining... the only text embedded as image are the *tech specs*: https://assets.razerzone.com/eeimages/products/26227/tech_spec_en.jpg

Comment: ...probably they have forgotten how to write a table in html! **;-)**

Answer (score 1):

Selecting text is not really disabled in the website you linked, so there is nothing to allow. It's just an image with text.

Whay you are looking for is some OCR extension, to extract text from images, I have successfully used this one: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/copyfish-%F0%9F%90%9F-free-ocr-soft/eenjdnjldapjajjofmldgmkjaienebbj/related?hl=en